# Tortoise SVN diff between revisions with different structure

Tags: svn, diff

I have code in subversion. Recently the way the code is structured was changed from this:

```
root/source-here
```

to:

```
root/folder 1/source-here
root/folder 2/other stuff
```

I went ahead and made a diff using Tortoise SVN but I didn't get what I expected. Basically all files (modified and new) are shown as added and all folders of original structure as deleted.

I say not expected but I'm not implying that its an error. I was expecting to see modified and added files.

Any idea on how to do this from the repository itself?

I think I can checkout both revs and compare locally with something like WinMerge but there should be a better way. I don't think this is an unique scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming rev 10 was when you did the move, you should be able to get the diffs like this:

```
svn diff http://server/svn/root/source-here@9 http://server/svn/root/folder1/source-here@10
```

Comment: That did the trick! Any way of doing that from Tortoise Subversion? Or add something to the command to export results to a diff file?

Comment: `svn help diff` will show you what it can output, and maybe using -x -u to get a unified diff will give you something you can open in Tortoise Merge. Beyond that, I'm not really sure of the best way to visualize the change you made.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is this?

`svn diff {banch1}/root/source-here {branch2}/root/folder1/source-here`

Comment: This might work if I was working with branches but I'm not. The structure difference is between revisions of the same branch.